What's a good approach to classification of surfaces' problems/drawing connected sums?
I’m trying to better understand classifications of surfaces and connected sums.
To start, I’m struggling to understand when given some surface (e.g. S^2 = sphere, T^2 = torus, P^2 = projective plane, etc…) how to transform them into images that involve the arrows. This may not be a straightforward question or clear, but it is as best as I can explain it.
Then following, how I can take some connected sum for example, T^2 # P^2 and draw it as a single hexagon with side identifiers. I can’t seem to find a good online resource to paint the intuition for me.
What would you recommend for resources, outlines, approaches to these types of problems? Thank you!

What textbook are you reading?

I believe its a textbook by Croom, Principles of Topology or something related to that title.

Hmm, so you are not quite sure what book it is. Did you check if it has answers to your questions? If it does not I can give you alternative suggestions.

No answers are provided. I was just interested in trying to develop some methodology or approach to problems like this. I would love to hear some suggestions!

Try "A guide to the classification theorem for compact surfaces" by Jean H Gallier Dianna Xu. I used it for teaching an undergraduate topology class on the classification on surfaces. The book does not skip on the details. It also contains some useful general topology background material.

Thank you very much!
